# how to scrape content using scrapy which have same class name

Tags: python, css, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape data from [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092890/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn) website but i'm having issue when scraping content from div which have same class name.

```
<div class="list">
   <a id="followed_by" name="followed_by"></a>
  <h4 class="li_group">Followed by</h4>
  <div class="soda odd"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0094450">Dirty Dancing</a></div>
  <div class="soda even"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0338096">Dirty Dancing: Havana Nights</a></div>
   <a id="version_of" name="version_of"></a>
  <h4 class="li_group">Version of</h4>
  <div class="soda odd"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt5262792">Dirty Dancing</a></div>
   <a id="remade_as" name="remade_as"></a>
  <h4 class="li_group">Remade as</h4>
  <div class="soda odd"><a href="http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0461062">Holiday</a></div>
</div>
```

i tried to use **xpath** but I'm having hard time when I'm trying to scrape from multiple pages. for example, when I'm trying to scrape from [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn) the xpath i used for the first page doesn't work.
Here Is The code I tried:

```
class ImdbSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "IMDB"
    allowed_domains = ["http://www.imdb.com"]
    start_urls = [l.strip() for l in open('1988.txt').readlines()]

    def parse(self, response):
        filename = response.url.split("/")[-2]
        open(filename, 'wb').write(response.body)
        item = ImdbcoItem
        for sel in response.xpath('body'):
            item['Followed_by'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="connections_content"]/div[2]/div[1]/a/text()').extract()
            item['version_of'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="connections_content"]/div[2]/div[3]/a/text()').extract()
            item['Remade_as'] = sel.xpath('//*[@id="connections_content"]/div[2]/div[4]/a/text()').extract()
        return item
```

I want my **Output** to be like this:
Followed By: Dirty Dancing, Dirty Dancing: Havana Nights
Version of: Dirty Dancing
Remade as: Holiday
Any Help Would Be Really Helpful!!

Comment: Can you update it with the result item from your `parse()` on some sample URL? Do not expect that readers here will always run your code (especially since it would require a local file `1988.txt`). Providing `input + code + **actual output** + expected output` makes better questions, increases the chances of a good answer.

Comment: @haben First of all put `item = ImdbcoItem` in the for loop and don't forget paste `()` should be `item = ImdbcoItem()`. Next, you shouldn't make `return item` only `yield item` and only in `for loop`

Comment: @haben don't use `/div[2]/div[4]` and like this also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give this a try. I hope it will solve the issue:

```
for sel in response.css("div.list"):
    item['Followed_by'] = sel.css("a#followed_by+h4.li_group+div.odd a::text").extract()
    item['version_of'] = sel.css("a#version_of+h4.li_group+div.odd a::text").extract()
    item['Remade_as'] = sel.css("a#remade_as+h4.li_group+div.odd a::text").extract()
return item
```

If "Followed by" fail to give you all the results then try it:

```
item['Followed_by'] = sel.css("a#followed_by+h4.li_group+div.odd a::text , a#followed_by+h4.li_group+div.odd+div.even a::text").extract()
```

Comment: It works like a charm!! Thanks, Just One More Thing, when I try to scrape [this](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0092455/trivia?tab=mc&ref_=tt_trv_cnn) page, the _Followed_by_ Item only extracts the 1st and 2nd Movie Title but there are about 15 Movie Titles. is there any way to scrape all movie titles not just 1st & 2nd?

Answer (score 0):

This may help

```
    desc = hxs.select('//div[@class = "list"]/text()').extract()
    and then try print(desc[0])
```