# How to select element that has class_A and has not class_B?

Tags: python, scrapy

My HTML code is:

```
<div>
    <span class="class_a">Text A</span>
    <span class="class_a class_b">Text AB</span>    
</div>
```

My css selector:

```
response.css('.class_a::text').extract()
```

How should I modify it to get only `Text A` and skip `Text AB`?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to scrape content using scrapy which have same class name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940230/how-to-scrape-content-using-scrapy-which-have-same-class-name)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try the [*:not()*](https://developer.mozilla.org/fr/docs/Web/CSS/%3Anot) selector :

```
response.css('.class_a:not(.class_b)::text').extract()
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want with XPath 
`response.xpath('//span[@class="class_a"]/text()')`